# Creating google.visualization.DataTable() in java servlet using jstl

Tags: servlets, jstl

I am trying to chart some data using a Google Annotation chart. When I hard code my data in javascript as under, I get the chart properly

```
function drawChart() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
          data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
          data.addColumn('number','Level');
          data.addColumn('string', 'Activity');

          data.addRows([
            [new Date(2017,1,14,0, 1), 88,  undefined],
            [new Date(2017,1,14,0, 16), 83,  undefined],
            [new Date(2017,1,14,0, 31), 78,  undefined],
            ...
            [new Date(2017,1,14,23, 46), 74,  undefined]              
            ]);

 var chart = new google.visualization.AnnotationChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

    var options = {
      displayAnnotations: true
    };

    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

Now I am trying to replace the data.addrows section with a jstl forEach to iterate through the data from a java object "Readings" which has readingTime, readingLevel and readingAnnotation as parameters - but I don't get my chart - just get a blank page.

```
function drawChart() {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
      data.addColumn('number','Level');
      data.addColumn('string', 'Activity');

      <c:forEach items="${Readings}" var="entry">
      data.addRow(${entry.readingTime}, ${entry.readingValue}, ${entry.readingAnnotation});
      </c:forEach>


      var chart = new google.visualization.AnnotationChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

      var options = {
        displayAnnotations: true
      };

      chart.draw(data, options);
```

In another servlet, I used this loop to simply print the data values in my browser and that worked - so the loop is able to iterate through the "Readings" list and read the parameters, but it is not creating the dataset like hardcoding the values does.

Any ideas on what I need to do to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

```
function drawChart() {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
      data.addColumn('number','Level');
      data.addColumn('string', 'Activity');
      var rows = []
      <c:forEach items="${Readings}" var="entry">
      rows.push([new Date(${entry.readingTime}), ${entry.readingValue}, ${entry.readingAnnotation}]);
      </c:forEach>
      data.addRow(rows);

      var chart = new google.visualization.AnnotationChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

      var options = {
        displayAnnotations: true
      };

      chart.draw(data, options);
```

Comment: Thanks Vikram. I updated my code (assuming the last curly bracket is a square bracket.) but the issue still persists..

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Never mind - i was able to see the generatd javascript and debug. The issues was that the String field was not placed in quotes when reading it to the row. Thanks for your help Vikram! The